# How do I get standard link to share pictures in dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I need to upload bulk pictures and get each of their links to share it. The link is not standard in dropbox.

Lets say I have two pictures, their names: 1.jpg and 2.jpg
I want to get standard links like:

http://www.dropbox.com/1.jpg, 
http://www.dropbox.com/2.jpg

is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dropbox API to get or create shared links for files. Specifically, you can use /2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings to create a shared link for a file or folder:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings

Or you can use /2/sharing/list_shared_links to get existing shared links:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links

There are also corresponding methods in the SDKs if you're using one:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation